# "Invalid Server URL" error after replacing .jar files while installing GraphDB

Tags: tomcat, installation, semantic-web, sesame, linked-data

I was trying to install GraphDB to complement default Sesame. Following the instructions for 'Easy Install' in http://owlim.ontotext.com/display/OWLIMv54/OWLIM-SE+Installation, I copied the .war files from GraphDB distribution to my Tomcat directory and replaced the pre-existing .war files that came with Sesame. However, I saw no 'OWLIM-SE' repositories in the Sesame drop down after restarting the server.

While troubleshooting, I replaced the .jar files in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\openrdf-sesame\WEB-INF\lib with those from the most recent Sesame version to see if it makes any difference (I had 2.8.3).

Difference it did make. I now get only the 'Change Server' page. Upon entering the URL of my server as http://my.ip.address:8080/openrdf-sesame, I get an "Invalid Server url" error. I had changed the server url from localhost to ip address so that I can access it externally. How can I resolve two issues:

1. Get Sesame working again
2. Install GraphDB

Following is the log:

```
Jul 08, 2015 4:41:24 PM org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator canConnect
WARNING: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://my.ip.address.here:8080/openrdf-sesame/protocol
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://my.ip.address.here/openrdf-sesame/protocol
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1834)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator.canConnect(ServerValidator.java:121)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator.isValidServer(ServerValidator.java:76)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.findWorkbenchServlet(WorkbenchGateway.java:251)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:121)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What component produced the "invalid server url" error message? That doesn't look familiar to me. Any stack traces in any log files?

Comment: Solved part of the problem. Deleting the 2 .war files and corresponding folders C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps and then copying fresh .war files from Sesame gets it working again. Since the repository data is stored elsewhere, I didn't lose it.

Now, I'm only left with getting GraphDB working. Replacing the .war files with those from its distribution doesn't work.

Comment: Try again, it should work (don't update to Sesame 2.8 though, GraphDB is still on Sesame 2.7). You may need to refresh/clear your cache for the option to show up, though.

Comment: Hi Jeen, I removed 2.8.4 and installed 2.7.16 instead. The GraphDB still doesn't work. I downloaded GraphDB-Lite. Does that make any difference? 

Also, I realized that all my previous repositories are listed but none of them open. When I click an old repository, I get  this error "HTTP Status 500 - No such repository: RepositoryName". I can create new repositories alright.

Clearing the browser cache didn't help as well.

Comment: Solved it. Although I'm not sure if this is the right way; hence not posting this as answer. I deleted the .war files from 2.7.16 and just added the ones from GraphDB. OWLIM-Lite is now available as an option. The only problem is I've lost the past repositories I had created. For some reason, a test repository I created today before installing GraphDB seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! Here's what worked:

```
I first installed GraphDB. Then, I replaced the jar files of GraphDB with those of Sesame 2.7.16. I copied the same set of files to the 'libs' folder of both Sesame-openrdf and Sesame-workbench. Though some jar files are duplicate, I did not remove one version for the other.
```

For anyone reading this, please note this is a risky workaround at best. Implementing CORS is a better option. More information is available at http://answers.ontotext.com/questions/1984/previous-functional-ajax-code-with-jsonp-not-working-with-graphdb-lite.